# PGFPlots: Math operations within coordinates yields error?

Tags: pgfplots, math-operators

How can I use math operators within PGFPlots coordinates?

When I write something like `\draw (axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs: sqrt(3),1)`, I get the following error:

> ¡ Argument of \pgfplots@evalute@tikz@coord@system@interface@ has an extra }.

However, `\draw (0,0) -> ({sqrt(3)},1)` works fine in Tikz, as long as `sqrt(3)` is written inside of braces `{}`.

If I add the braces to the PGFPlots code, I get the follwing error:

> ¡ Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '-{sqrt(3)}/2' as a floating po
>   int number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'sqrt(3)/2'..

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.8,
    standard/.style={
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        axis z line=center,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        zlabel={$z$},
        axis line style=help lines,
        every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
    }
}

\begin{document}

{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

    \begin{axis}[
        standard,
        hide z axis,
        xmin=-1.25, xmax=1.25,
        ymin=-1.25, ymax=1.25,
        zmin=0, zmax=2.5,
        xtick={-1,1},
        xticklabels={$-2r$,$2r$},
        ytick=\empty,
    ]
        % Draw Circle
        \draw[blue] (axis cs: 0,0,0)
            ellipse [
            x radius=1, y radius=1];

        % Draw Square
        \draw[green]    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,0.5,0) --
                    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,-0.5,0) --
                    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,-0.5,1) --
                    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,0.5,1) --
                    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,0.5,0);
%   I can't use math operators within PGFPlots apparently?
%       \draw[green]    (axis cs: -sqrt(3)/2,1/2,0) --
%                   (axis cs: -sqrt(3)/2,-1/2,0) --
%                   (axis cs: -sqrt(3)/2,-1/2,1) --
%                   (axis cs: -sqrt(3)/2,1/2,1) --
%                   (axis cs: -sqrt(3)/2,1/2,0);
    \end{axis}

% However, I am able to do so in regular Tikz, as long as I put functions like sqrt() in braces...
    \draw[green]    (-{sqrt(3)/2},1/2,0) ->
                (-{sqrt(3)/2},-1/2,0) ->
                (-{sqrt(3)/2},-1/2,1) ->
                (-{sqrt(3)/2},1/2,1) ->
                (-{sqrt(3)/2},1/2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you can't write arbitrary expressions in PGFPlots functions. The parser is looking for a single floating-point number, not an expression that it must evaluate in order to obtain a single floating-point number. What you can do is save the result of `-sqrt(3)/2` in a macro, and then call that macro each time. You have to do the same thing with your `1/2` and `-1/2` expressions, or else just replace those with `0.5` and `-0.5`.

Fixed code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.8,
    standard/.style={
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        axis z line=center,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        zlabel={$z$},
        axis line style=help lines,
        every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
    }
}

\begin{document}

{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

    \begin{axis}[
        standard,
        hide z axis,
        xmin=-1.25, xmax=1.25,
        ymin=-1.25, ymax=1.25,
        zmin=0, zmax=2.5,
        xtick={-1,1},
        xticklabels={$-2r$,$2r$},
        ytick=\empty,
    ]
        % Draw Circle
        \draw[blue] (axis cs: 0,0,0)
            ellipse [
            x radius=1, y radius=1];

        % Draw Square
        \draw[green]    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,0.5,0) --
                    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,-0.5,0) --
                    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,-0.5,1) --
                    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,0.5,1) --
                    (axis cs: -0.86602540378,0.5,0);
%   I can't use math operators within PGFPlots apparently?
      \pgfmathsetmacro\foo{-sqrt(3)/2}
      \draw[green]    (axis cs: \foo,0.5,0) --
                  (axis cs: \foo,-0.5,0) --
                  (axis cs:\foo,-0.5,1) --
                  (axis cs:\foo,0.5,1) --
                  (axis cs:\foo,0.5,0);
    \end{axis}

% However, I am able to do so in regular Tikz, as long as I put functions like sqrt() in braces...
    \draw[green]    (-{sqrt(3)/2},1/2,0) ->
                (-{sqrt(3)/2},-1/2,0) ->
                (-{sqrt(3)/2},-1/2,1) ->
                (-{sqrt(3)/2},1/2,1) ->
                (-{sqrt(3)/2},1/2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Super convenient! Now I only need to define the real numbers manually.