# Is it possible to draw a whole plot with a command?

Tags: pgfplots, macros

Basically I am going to use a lot of very similar plots, with a difference in the placement of 2 boundaries, and the position of 2 labels, so I would like to be able to just enter those 2 numbers as arguments, and let LaTeX take care of it. My failed attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

%zc,zt
\NewDocumentCommand{\hypplot}{ m m }
    {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                no markers, domain=-4:4, 
                samples=100, axis lines*=left,
                every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of     origin),anchor=west},
                height=5cm, width=12cm, 
                ytick=\empty, xtick=\empty,
                enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
                y axis line style={draw=none},
                ]

                %%Shade the area for alpha
                \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-4:#1] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle; 

                %%Shade the area for p-value
                \addplot [fill=orange!20, draw=none, domain=#1:#2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle; 

                %%draw the gaussian
                \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(0,1)};

                %%draws a double-headed arrow for Zc
                \draw [latex-latex] (axis cs:#1,-0.07) -- node [fill=white] {$\displaystyle \zcl{c}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$} (axis cs:0,0.-0.07);

                %%draws a double-headed arrow for Zt
                \draw [yshift=-0.6cm, latex-latex] (axis cs:#2,0.16) -- (axis cs:0,0.16);

                %%Label Zt
                \draw [yshift=-0.6cm](axis cs:(#1+#2)/2,0.22) node {$\displaystyle \zcl{T}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$};

                %%label the mean
                \draw (axis cs:0,.43) node {$\mu=\mu_0^{}$};
                \addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(0, 0) (0, 0.3989)};

                %%add alpha
                \draw (axis cs:#1*1.071,0.02) node {$\alpha$};  
                \addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(#1, -.01) (#1, 0.08)};
                \draw (axis cs:#1*1.02,0.10) node {$\bar{x}_c^{}$};

                %add p-value border
                \addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(#2, -.01) (#2, 0.22)};
                \draw (axis cs:#2*1.02,0.25) node {$\bar{x}$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}

\hypplot{-1.96}{-1.08}

\end{document}
```

I suppose I can always just copy paste and change each of them, but wouldn't it be nice to have a command to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it would be nice. And if you copy and paste the code from the `\hypplot` comand and only replace the `#1` and `#2` to `-1.96` and `-1.08` you still get an error.

The problem is that PFGPlots does not accept expressions when parsing a coordinate ([see this question about it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122427/81905)) so if you just parse the expressions with `\pgfmathparse` and then pass the results with `\pgfmathresult` whenever you had an expression inside a coordinate it works just fine:

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

%zc,zt
\NewDocumentCommand{\hypplot}{ m m }
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ no markers, domain=-4:4, 
                samples=100, axis lines*=left,
                every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, anchor=west},
                height=5cm, width=12cm, 
                ytick=\empty, xtick=\empty,
                enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
                y axis line style={draw=none}
                ]
    %%Shade the area for alpha
    \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-4:#1] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle; 

    %%Shade the area for p-value
    \addplot [fill=orange!20, draw=none, domain=#1:#2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle; 

    %%draw the gaussian
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(0,1)};

    %%draws a double-headed arrow for Zc
    \draw [latex-latex] (axis cs:#1,-0.07) -- node [fill=white] {$\displaystyle \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$} (axis cs:0,0.-0.07);

    %%draws a double-headed arrow for Zt
    \draw [yshift=-0.6cm, latex-latex] (axis cs:#2,0.16) -- (axis cs:0,0.16);

    %%Label Zt
    \pgfmathparse{#1+#2)/2}
    \draw [yshift=-0.6cm](axis cs:(\pgfmathresult,0.22) node {$\displaystyle \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$};

    %%label the mean
    \draw (axis cs:0,.43) node {$\mu=\mu_0^{}$};
    \addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(0, 0) (0, 0.3989)};

    %%add alpha
    \pgfmathparse{#1*1.071}
    \draw (axis cs:\pgfmathresult,0.02) node {$\alpha$};  
    \addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(#1, -.01) (#1, 0.08)};
    \pgfmathparse{#1*1.02}
    \draw (axis cs:\pgfmathresult,0.10) node {$\bar{x}_c^{}$};

    %add p-value border
    \pgfmathparse{#2*1.02}
    \addplot +[mark=none] coordinates {(#2, -.01) (#2, 0.22)};
    \draw (axis cs:\pgfmathresult,0.25) node {$\bar{x}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\hypplot{-1.96}{-1.08}
\end{document}
```